# regex expression for aws gateway

Tags: regex, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I need to configure the regex expression of an AWS Gateway endpoint in order to catch responses that contains either "error", "Error" or "ErrorMessage" strings.. I tried with "error.*" but that doesn't catch "ErrorMessage".

Comment: In what language/environment? Is the response not structured in some way? (json/xml)  `"error.*"` would likely match in *case insensitive* mode.

Comment: it is mapped to a lambda function that runs node.js and returns json. but as far as I understand, Gateway is agnostic of the backend: regarding error handling, it treats the answer as text plain.

Comment: @AlexK., what makes you think matching is case insensitive? I have a similar issue, and so far matching is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> (error|Error|ErrorMessage).*